# AttributeError: module 'PIL.ImageTk' has no attribute 'PhotoImage', how to fix this?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, attributes, python-imaging-library

I have written this so far: Its supposed to be showing a certain screan as i've tried to link an image that i have on pycharm.

```
import PIL
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def login_page():
    signup_window.destroy()
    import signin

signup_window = Tk()

signup_window.title ('Sign up page')
signup_window.resizable(False,False)
background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='bg.jpg')
bgLabel = Label(signup_window,image=background)
bgLabel.grid()


signup_window.mainloop()
```

However the problem is that it comes up with this error:

```py
    bgImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='bg.jpg')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'PIL.ImageTk' has no attribute 'PhotoImage'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: It worked for me Pyhthon 3.12.00rc3. Not using PYcharm. You must update Pycharm.